# Using custom functions in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class

I am trying to follow the short example in the following answer on using custom functions in rails:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879679/where-to-put-code-snippets-in-rails
```

In math.rb in lib/math.rb

```
module Math
    class << self
        def cube_it(num)
          num*3
        end
    end
end
```

In rails console I have tried

```
include Math
Math.cube_it(2)
```

But I get the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'cube_it' for Math:module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check config/application.rb for next line

```
# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

So if you have still unloadable extension you can type

```
require 'math'
```

and recheck

instead of call require, you can create config/initializers/lib.rb

with

> Dir[File.join(Rails.root, "lib", "*.rb")].each {|l| require l }

Comment: I have added the above line, and also rebooted my linode server however I still get the same error. When I type **include Math** into rails console it returns object, when I type **Math.cube_it(2)** afterwards it gives the same error

Comment: try reload! and then Math.methods.grep /cube/

Comment: it only can mean that your extension still unloaded. Check methods which Math contains from console , as I mentioned above

Comment: When I do the above that you suggested **try reload! and then Math.methods.grep /cube/** it returns **[]**

Comment: strange... It just means that your extenstion still unloaded